# Set the product type when creating a product programmatically in Woocommerce 3

Tags: php, wordpress, class, methods, woocommerce

In Woocommerce, I am trying to find a way similar to the `WC_Product` methods `set_name()` or `set_status()` for example, to set the product type like **Simple** or **Variation**.

Actually I use the `WC_Product` object like this :

```
    $product = new WC_Product;

    $product->set_name($data['product']['title']);

    $product->set_status('pending');

    $product->save();
```

How can I **set the product type** if user check "simple product" or "variable product"?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

There is no type method for the `WC_Product` class. The product type is managed by product sub classes…

You will first get an empty instance of `WC_Product` object for the desired product type:

1. **Variable** type: `$product = new WC_Product_Variable();`
2. **Grouped** type: `$product = new WC_Product_Grouped();`
3. **External** type: `$product = new WC_Product_External();`
4. **Simple** type: `$product = new WC_Product_Simple();`

Then you can use on the selected product type any `WC_product` method or the corresponding Product sub Class methods on the `$product` object:

```
$product->set_name($data['product']['title']);
$product->set_status('publish');
```

Then you will save the product *(and it will return the product ID optionally)*:

```
$product_id = $product->save();
```

> **See:** [Create programmatically a product using CRUD methods in Woocommerce 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52937409/create-programmatically-a-product-using-crud-methods-in-woocommerce-3)

---

**Product Variations**

For product variations, it's different as they are always part of an existing Variable product…

```
// Get the Variable product object (parent) from an existing product ID
$product = wc_get_product( $product_id );

// Define the variation data
$variation_post = array(
    'post_title'  => $product->get_title(),
    'post_name'   => 'product-'.$product_id.'-variation',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'post_parent' => $product_id,
    'post_type'   => 'product_variation',
    'guid'        => $product->get_permalink()
);

// Creating the product variation
$variation_id = wp_insert_post( $variation_post );

// Get an instance of the product variation Object
$variation = new WC_Product_Variation( $variation_id );

// Set existing product attribute values (defined in the variable product)
$variation->update_meta_data( 'attribute_'.'pa_color', 'blue' );
$variation->update_meta_data( 'attribute_'.'pa_size', 'xxl' );

# You can use any WC_Product allowed setter methods on the $variation object

$variation->set_regular_price( 25 );
$variation->set_price( 25 );

$variation->save();
```

See those 2 related threads:

- [Create programmatically a WooCommerce product variation with new attribute values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47518280/create-programmatically-a-woocommerce-product-variation-with-new-attribute-value/47766413#47766413)
- [Create programmatically a variable product and two new attributes in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47518333/create-programmatically-a-variable-product-and-two-new-attributes-in-woocommerce/47844054#47844054)

Comment: May I suggest the use of the function WC_Product_Factory::get_classname_from_product_type() to get the classname. Although, this function currently does essentially nothing in the future WooCommerce may implement a hook which you will not see if you don't use the API.

Comment: @user9372991 You have give your answer and I have give mine… Each one has its advantages and disadvantages, but both works depending on the requirements needed, which is not really clear in that question. We will see what comes on futur. Now its today and there is many ways hopefully.

Comment: Your answer is absolutely the right one, my answer is really answering a tangential question from something remarked in another answer out of curiosity.

Comment: @user9372991 I have mostly never used WC_Product_Factory… But it's a good track and your answer is valuable too. The only weakness is with that way it seems that you need to have a free new post ID (or an existing one) to make it work.

Answer (score 3):

I am a little late to the party but you can also do this now to change the product type.

```
function your_function() {
    $product_id = 111;
    wp_set_object_terms( $product_id, 'variable', 'product_type' );
}
```

Comment: late to the party and a life saver

Answer (score 0):

The type is typically set when you create the product:

```
$prod_data = [
    'name'          => 'A great product',
    'type'          => 'simple',
    'regular_price' => '15.00',
    'description'   => 'A very meaningful product description',
    'images'        => [
        [
            'src'      => 'https://shop.local/path/to/image.jpg',
            'position' => 0,
        ],
    ],
    'categories'    => [
        [
            'id' => 1,
        ],
    ],
];

$woocommerce->post( 'products', $prod_data );
```

I'm not sure if there is a function to modify the type of product, but it can be modified using the REST API:

```
$api_response = wp_remote_post( 'https://your-website/wp-json/wc/v2/products/{PRODUCT ID}', array(
    //'method'    => 'PUT',
    'headers' => array(
        'Authorization' => 'Basic ' . base64_encode( 'KEY:SECRET' )
    ),
    'body' => array(
        'type' => 'simple', // just update the product type
        // Options: simple, grouped, external and variable
        // more params http://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/?shell#product-properties
    )
) );

$body = json_decode( $api_response['body'] );
//print_r( $body );

if( wp_remote_retrieve_response_message( $api_response ) === 'OK' ) {
    echo 'The product ' . $body->name . ' has been updated';
}
```

Comment: "I'm not sure if there is a function to modify the type of product" - There is no function AFAIK but the functionality is in WooCommerce - see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Although WooCommerce doesn't expose an API for changing the product type, in fact WooCommerce does implement this functionality as it is necessary to support changing the product type using the 'Product Type' select box on the admin pages like https:://aaa.bbb.ccc/wp-admin/post.php?post=12345&action=edit. The code for this is essentially the following:

```
    $classname = WC_Product_Factory::get_product_classname( $post_id, $product_type );
    $product   = new $classname( $post_id );
    $product->save();
```

Note that a product type conversion is occurring here as the product type of the existing product with id == $post_id may be different from $product_type. Apparently it is ok to use the product constructor of a different type then what was used to originally construct the product. It seems strange but that is what the WooCommerce code does when you change the product type in the admin page.

The REST API implements a change of product type in essentially the same way.

Comment: So instead of use JS for just create a submission form with WC API. But it's the same problem. If i understand the WC logic by default a product is a simple product  (type) so the best way is to create a radio button. But how do that if Woocommerce doesn't expose an API for changing the product type ?

Comment: For initial product creation the answer of LoicTheAztec is exactly what you want (but you should use the WC_Product_Factory::get_product_classname() to get the classname). This answer is in response to the remark of @entreprenerds - "I'm not sure if there is a function to modify the type of product". If you need to change the product type of an existing product programmatically then you can just execute directly the code I have given. The point is although WooCommerce does not expose an API function for changing the product type it has to implement that functionality to support the admin page

Comment: However, if WooCommerce should drastically change the implementation of products it may change how product type is changed on existing products. In this case WooCommerce would replace the given code with something else so it is dangerous to use code that is dependent on the current implementation and not wrap in an API function.