# WooCommerce programmatically created product ignores prices sorting filter

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, woocommerce, product

I have following function to create new woocommerce product on the frontend.

```
parse_str($_POST['form_data'], $form_data);
$insertPost = array(
    //'ID'          => $post_id,
    'post_title' => $form_data['post_title'],
    'post_status' => $form_data['post_status'],
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'post_content' => $form_data['post_content']
);
$insert_post = wp_insert_post( $insertPost, true);
update_post_meta( $insert_post, 'hours', $form_data['hours'] );
update_post_meta( $insert_post, 'year', $form_data['year'] );
update_post_meta( $insert_post, '_weight', $form_data['_weight'] );
update_post_meta( $insert_post, '_price', $form_data['_regular_price'] );
update_post_meta( $insert_post, '_regular_price', $form_data['_regular_price'] );
update_post_meta( $insert_post, '_sale_price', $form_data['_sale_price'] );
update_post_meta( $insert_post, '_stock_status', $form_data['_stock_status'] );
$term_taxonomy_ids = wp_set_object_terms( $insert_post, array(15), 'product_cat' );
wp_set_object_terms( $insert_post, 'simple', 'product_type' );
```

The code above is creating a new product and adding all data to it as expected.
The issue is when using the sort by price filter, the sorting doesn't really sort the newly product created in proper way, it just ignores it.

After searching i found in WooCommerce > Status > Tools > Product lookup tables (regenerate)
once i click the regenerate button, then it regenerate all product data and the price sorting is working as expected.

So what is missing in my function to make the price sorting work without regenerate button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some custom WooCommerce database tables and cached data that your outdated code doesn't handle, so use the following *(using `WC_Product` methods)* like:

```
parse_str($_POST['form_data'], $form_data);

// Get an empty instance of the WC_Product Object (with the correct product type)
$product = new WC_Product_Simple(); // "simple" product type

$product->set_name($form_data['post_title']);
$product->set_status($form_data['post_status']);
$product->set_description($form_data['post_content']);

if( isset($form_data['post_excerpt']) ) {
    $product->set_short_description($form_data['post_excerpt']); // Optional
}

$product->add_meta_data('hours', $form_data['hours']);
$product->add_meta_data('year', $form_data['year']);

$product->set_price($form_data['_regular_price']);
$product->set_regular_price($form_data['_regular_price']);
$product->set_sale_price($form_data['_sale_price']);

$product->set_weight($form_data['_weight']);

$product->set_stock_status($form_data['_stock_status']);

$product->set_category_ids( array(15) );

$product->save(); // Save to database
```

It should work now with "sort by price filter" without regenerating product data.

Related: [Create programmatically a product using CRUD methods in Woocommerce 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52937409/create-programmatically-a-product-using-crud-methods-in-woocommerce-3/52941994#52941994)

Comment: I have used follwoing WP_REST_Request . it works fine now. i am wondering if your suggestion is safer / better to use?
`$data = [
            'name' => $form_data['post_title'],
            'description' => $form_data['post_content'],
            'regular_price' => $form_data['_regular_price']
        ];
        $request = new WP_REST_Request( 'POST' );
        $request->set_body_params( $data );
        $products_controller = new WC_REST_Products_Controller;
        $response = $products_controller->create_item( $request );`